# When is the graph of the divisor relation on $[n]$ planar?

Tags: graph-theory

A recently-deleted question asked to show that if $G(n)$ is the graph on $[n]=\{1,\dots,n\}$ where $x$ and $y$ are adjacent if $x|y$ or $y|x$, then $G(n)$ is planar.  This is false if $n\geq150$, for the subgraph induced by $\{2,3,5,90,120,150\}$ is isomorphic to $K_{3,3}$.

My question is, what is the largest value of $n$ such that $G(n)$ is planar?  Of course, various software packages would make short work of this, but I'd be interested in a verbal argument, if someone can give one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be no greater than $15$, as $\{1,2,4,8,16\}$ gives a $K_5$.  I was able to draw the graph for $14$, shown partially completed below.  $1-6$ has to go inside so that $3-12$ can go outside, but I think it is clear how to complete it.  If you try to do it on $15$ you fail because merging $5,10,15$ makes a $K_{3,3}$ with $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{6,12,5-10-15\}$.  Even if you swap $7,14$ with $5,10$ so $15$ can go in the region to connect to both $3$ and $5$ it blocks the $1-6$ connection.

[image]

Comment: I tried this on nauty and it says that $G(14)$ is planar and $G(15)$ is nonplanar.  Please check your graph for $n=15$ and I'll check if it's to get nauty to tell me what the obstruction in $G(15)$ is.  Good catch on $G(16).$  I should have thought of that.  Perhaps you meant to say you were able to draw the graph for $14$?

Comment: The problem I see is you can't connect $15$ to both $3$ and $5$.

Comment: So when you say "I was able to draw the graph for $15$" you meant to say $14$?

Comment: @saulspatz:  yes, I realized there was no place to put $15$ here.  I then found the $K_{3,3}$ that prohibits it.

Comment: That does it.  Excellent.